# не могу подключить FloatLayout

Tags: python, kivy

помогите разобраться с кодом , 2 часа не могу понять почему не работает
main.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivymd.theming import ThemeManager
# from kivymd.navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer
#from navigationdrawer import NavigationDrawer
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window

Window.size = (480, 853)

class ProductScreen(Floatlayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()

#if __name__ == '__name__':
MyApp().run(
```

tk.kv

```
<ProductScreen@Screen>:
    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: None
        height: root.height - toolbar.height

        FitImage:
            source: "smokestackheather.jpeg"
```

Comment: А что такое `Container()` и почему вы возвращаете его в методе `build`?

Answer (score 0):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout 

Window.size = (480, 853)

class Container(FloatLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Container()

#if __name__ == '__name__':
MyApp().run()



<Container>:
    Button:
        text: 'Helloy'
```